# Fail to assigned to the output parameter in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[loginCheck]
    @uid AS int ,
    @pwd AS nchar(50) ,
    @result AS INT OUTPUT 
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM seller WHERE S_id = @uid AND S_password = @pwd)
    BEGIN
        SET @result = 1
        EXEC(@result)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @result = 0 
        EXEC(@result)
    END
END
```

This is the code of my stored procedure, I want to check out the id and password when login, so I check if there exists this data in my database.

```
declare @result int
exec loginCheck 1, '123456', @result output
select @result
```

I use these to test my stored procedure, but it informed there exist grammatical errors around "1", when i debug by each statement, I found `@result` has changed to 1, so why i got this error, and how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Remove `EXEC(@result)`. There is nothing to execute.

Comment: but if i remove it, the procedure will return me NULL

Comment: @盛振华, did you try to remove the EXEC as Alex suggested?  The output parameter `@result` should be 0 or 1 after the proc completes.

Comment: @Alex Kudryashev, fixed as you say, thanks a lot

Comment: Please tell us you're ***NOT*** storing the passwords in **clear text** in your database!!!! Don't ever ever do that!!!

Comment: Thanks for reminding, and don' t worry, it is just my homework on a lesson